# Some doubts about Linux partition managment

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, mount, sd-card

I am not very experienced using Linux and I have the following situation that cause me some doubts.

I have wrote RaspBian (the RaspBerry linux distribution) on an SD card using this command on Ubuntu:

```
sudo dd if=2014-01-07-wheezy-raspbian.img of=/dev/sdb bs=1024
```

So if now I run the `fdisk -l` command I obtain that I have 2 partitions on my SD card:

```
Dispositivo Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            8192      122879       57344    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/sdb2          122880     5785599     2831360   83  Linux
```

And now the first doubt: the **dd** command creates two partitions on the SD card:

1. **/dev/sdb1** that is a litle **FAT32** partition (what it means (LBA)?)
2. **/dev/sdb2** that is a larger **Linux ext3** partition

The question is: why it also creates a **FAT32** partition and not only a **Linux ext3** partition?

If I go into my computer resource I can see a device (related to my SD card) into the devices list that contains some RaspBian file, following a screenshot:

[image]

And if I see the property of this device I obtain this:

[image: device properties]

So, looking at the previous screenshot it seems to me that this is the small FAT32 partition, and now I have the followings doubts:

If it is the smallest FAT32 partition, what contains? The RaspBian boot or what?

Why, in the devices list, I have only the FAT32 partition and not also the Linux one (/dev/sdb2), to see it have I to mount it? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The partition table of a disk lives on sector 0.  You can overwrite a disk's (SD card's, etc.) partition table by overwritng this sector with `dd`, which is what happened.

FAT32 is understood by both Linux and Windows systems.  If you place an `ext` formatted disk or SD card in a Windows system, Windows will ask you to format it.  If, however, you have a "buffer" FAT32 partition, Windows will mount and open that instead.  Windows does not open or touch any other partition on a removeable drive or card other than the first.  So this may have been done to prevent an accidental format in case it's put in a Windows system.  (It also may be that the boot firmware of the RPi only understands FAT32 as well).